# Including assets conditionally in twig

Tags: javascript, symfony, assetic

In my twig template I include javascript files like this:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% javascripts
        "@SomeBundle/Resources/public/js/eventendpage.js"
        "@SomeBundle/Resources/public/js/eventList.js"
        "@SomeBundle/Resources/public/js/containerList/container-list.js"
    %}
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock javascripts %}
```

This template is used for several custom contents, and I want to conditionally include other JS files, for example, if the template variable `type` equals "form", I want to include one more file like "@SomeBundle/Resources/public/js/Form/form-validation.js" beside the other ones.

How can I do this if there is any other way?

Comment: have you tried
`{% if type == 'form' %}
include my js
{% endif %}`
?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading resources conditionally with Assetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417521/loading-resources-conditionally-with-assetic)